# MySQL swaps on system with more than enough RAM

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7, percona-server, numa

Om my new dual AMD EPYC 7401 24-Core (128G RAM) MySQL starts swapping even after a restart with no data in memory.

**NUMA**

```
# numactl --hardware
available: 8 nodes (0-7)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 48 49 50 51 52 53
node 0 size: 32114 MB
node 0 free: 198 MB
node 1 cpus: 6 7 8 9 10 11 54 55 56 57 58 59
node 1 size: 32232 MB
node 1 free: 124 MB
node 2 cpus: 12 13 14 15 16 17 60 61 62 63 64 65
node 2 size: 0 MB
node 2 free: 0 MB
node 3 cpus: 18 19 20 21 22 23 66 67 68 69 70 71
node 3 size: 0 MB
node 3 free: 0 MB
node 4 cpus: 24 25 26 27 28 29 72 73 74 75 76 77
node 4 size: 32253 MB
node 4 free: 136 MB
node 5 cpus: 30 31 32 33 34 35 78 79 80 81 82 83
node 5 size: 32227 MB
node 5 free: 212 MB
node 6 cpus: 36 37 38 39 40 41 84 85 86 87 88 89
node 6 size: 0 MB
node 6 free: 0 MB
node 7 cpus: 42 43 44 45 46 47 90 91 92 93 94 95
node 7 size: 0 MB
node 7 free: 0 MB
node distances:
node   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
  0:  10  16  16  16  32  32  32  32 
  1:  16  10  16  16  32  32  32  32 
  2:  16  16  10  16  32  32  32  32 
  3:  16  16  16  10  32  32  32  32 
  4:  32  32  32  32  10  16  16  16 
  5:  32  32  32  32  16  10  16  16 
  6:  32  32  32  32  16  16  10  16 
  7:  32  32  32  32  16  16  16  10
```

**MySQL config**

```
# cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
# Ansible managed


[client]
port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
ssl_cert = /etc/mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl_key = /etc/mysql/client-key.pem

[mysqld_safe]
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice = 0
flush_caches = 1

[mysqld]
user = mysql
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid_file = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
general_log = 0
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 0
slow_query_log = 0
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
skip_external_locking = 1
skip_name_resolve = 1
max_connections = 1500
back_log = 1024
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
character_set_server = utf8
collation_server = utf8_general_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
init_connect = 'SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci; SET NAMES utf8;'
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
key_buffer_size = 32M
myisam_recover_options = FORCE,BACKUP
thread_stack = 256K
thread_cache_size = 750
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 256M
group_concat_max_len = 256M
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
open_files_limit = 65535
innodb_open_files = 8192
table_definition_cache = 8192
table_open_cache = 8192
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64G
innodb_log_file_size = 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 12
innodb_read_io_threads = 12
innodb_io_capacity = 7500
innodb_numa_interleave = 1
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0
performance_schema = 0
ssl_ca = /etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl_cert = /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl_key = /etc/mysql/server-key.pem

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 256M

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size = 32M
```

As far as I can see there're some NUMA nodes with no RAM left, is that that reason for swapping? How can I prevent this (e.g. NUMA seems to be configured in MySQL)?

And although the machine is swapping, performance seems pretty good. Do I need to worry for MySQL to be killed?

**Processes using memory**

```
# for i in $(ls -d /proc/[0-9]*) 
> do  
>    out=$(grep Swap $i/status 2>/dev/null)
>    if [ "x$(echo $out | awk '{print $2}')" != "x0" ] && [ "x$(echo $out | awk '{print $2}')" != "x" ]
>    then    
>   echo "$(ps -p $(echo $i | cut -d'/' -f3) \
>          | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4'}): $(echo $out | awk '{print $2 $3}')" 
>    fi
> done
systemd-journal: 92kB
perl: 1364kB
/usr/bin/pt-dis: 1452kB
sshd: 8kB
bash: 76kB
mysqld: 204436kB
sshd: 4kB
bash: 24kB
```

[image: htop]

**Swap setting**

```
vm.swappiness=1
```

**Number of (filled) memory slots**

```
# dmidecode -t memory | grep -i size
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
```

**lshw (memory) output**

```
# lshw -class memory
  *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: HPE
       physical id: 5
       version: A40
       date: 01/25/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory:0
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 15
       slot: System board or motherboard
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 0
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 1
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 1
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 2
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 2
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 3
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 3
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 4
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:4
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 4
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 5
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:5
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 5
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 6
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:6
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 6
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 7
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:7
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 7
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 8
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:8
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 8
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 9
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:9
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 9
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 10
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:10
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: a
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 11
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:11
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: b
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 12
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:12
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: c
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 13
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:13
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: d
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 14
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:14
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: e
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 15
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:15
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: f
          slot: PROC 1 DIMM 16
          width: 64 bits
  *-memory:1
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 16
       slot: System board or motherboard
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 0
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 1
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 1
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 2
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 2
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 3
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 3
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 4
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:4
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 4
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 5
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:5
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 5
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 6
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:6
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 6
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 7
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:7
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 7
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 8
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:8
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 8
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 9
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:9
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: 9
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 10
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:10
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: a
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 11
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:11
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: b
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 12
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:12
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: c
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 13
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:13
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: d
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 14
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:14
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: e
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 15
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:15
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: NOT AVAILABLE
          vendor: UNKNOWN
          physical id: f
          slot: PROC 2 DIMM 16
          width: 64 bits
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 81
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 2304KiB
       capacity: 2304KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 82
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 12MiB
       capacity: 12MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 83
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 64MiB
       capacity: 64MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-cache:3
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 85
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 2304KiB
       capacity: 2304KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:4
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 86
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 12MiB
       capacity: 12MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:5
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 87
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 64MiB
       capacity: 64MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 0
  *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 1
```

https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-5947

Comment: hi, try first to check - what process used memory (top or htop), check - https://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-memory-usage/

Comment: Added the swap usage details

Comment: yes, but what process use real memory? you haven't free memory, so mysql start use swap, so you need to confirm - is it mysql use real memory or another process

Comment: Added htop screenshot

Comment: sorry, you use NUMA system, I haven't it personally but see some descriptions of similar errors, like - https://www.fromdual.com/do-not-underestimate-performance-impacts-of-swapping-on-numa-database-systems

Comment: test first as suggested - Set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 75% of half of your RAM, this is what I think first (reduce innodb memory for test)

Comment: I set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 75% of half of your RAM. Performance increased, but it is still swapping (but a little bit less)

Comment: The fact that swap is _used_ doesn't mean swapping is actually happening presently. Use `sar -BW` to see if it is.

Answer (score 1):

Nice to meet you, Mischa. We discussed this in person but I thought I'd put some ideas out here for anyone else to reference and we could continue some discussion here. ;)

Looking at your information provided above, the thing that stands out most to me is that you have 8 total NUMA nodes, but only 4 of them have memory attached to them. I don't know too much about the AMD EPYC architecture, so I'm learning in real time, but this is typically a bad configuration, and one that can cause problems.

In particular I am not sure how Linux's NUMA interleave node behaves when it's interleaved across all nodes, but not all nodes actually have memory – I think you could easily get into interesting edge cases either with performance, or e.g. swapping.

It would be interesting to try a few things and see how the performance and behavior differs:

- Using `numactl` to limit `mysqld` to interleave only on the nodes which actually have memory, this should be e.g. `numactl --interleave=0,1,4,5`
- Adjusting your physical memory configuration to use twice as many DIMMs of half the size. I'd guess you have 8 x 16 GiB DIMMs now, so you could potentially try a configuration with 16 x 8 GiB DIMMs instead, populating **all** DIMM sockets.
- Adjusting your physical memory configuration to use twice as much RAM could also be interesting (at least as a test), just populating all sockets with your current size DIMMs.
- Again assuming you're currently using 8 x 16 GiB DIMMs, adjusting your physical memory configuration to populate one DIMM slot per channel (which is also per-NUMA-node) instead of two DIMMs in a single channel and some channels unpopulated. It looks like AMD recommends this as well in their [memory population guidelines for AMD EPYC processors](https://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/56301_1.0.pdf).

I am very interested to hear what the end result of this is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

`numactl --interleave=all`. Or: `innodb_numa_interleave=1`, available as a MySQL VARIABLE as of 5.6.27.  More discussion : http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory#numa

I *may* be that the OS has decided to take residence in the 'first' core, and ran out of space in the memory hanging off that core.  By using "interleave" you declare that RAM is really spread around all the cores.  This is reasonable for a single-purpose machine, such as a dedicated db server.  Non-interleave may make sense if you are trying to dedicate certain processes to certain cores and give them their adjacent memory (for a slight performance boost).

Comment: I'm already using flush_caches = 1 and innodb_numa_interleave = 1. On all my other machines (dual soc Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620, percona 5.6 and single sock AMD EPYC 7401P, percona 5.7) this seems to work fine, but not here